# How to represent external API in class diagramm

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

This is my actual class diagram

[image]

In the `LocationVertex`class I have used the type `Location` which is an object from Flickr

API .

Should I indicate the use of external API in my diagram? and how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preferance but i would propably add them to give a better understanding of the workings of your project to anyone interested.

Don't think there is a standard for it but i'd go for displaying it as an interface with the full import name and the stereotype external. If you also display packages it might be a good way to differentiate.
In the end i think it's all "can do" options and whatever you deem understandable goes...